# Need to create a multiplication table in a very specific way after getting 2 inputs from the user

Tags: c++, c++14

We're learning about for loops in my C++ class and we are asked to get 2 inputs from the user between 2 and 10. Then produce a table that looks something like this: (in this example the two inputs were 5 and 7)

```
.....1...2...3...4...5...6...7
.1...1...2...3...4...5...6...7
.2...2...4...6...8..10..12..14
.3...3...6...9..12..15..18..21
.4...4...8..12..16..20..24..28
.5...5..10..15..20..25..30..35
```

basically where each of the numbers on the axis are multiplied and then displayed in the middle (multiplication table). I am comfortable with iomanip and don't need help with alignment of the numbers. I just don't fully understand how to produce the actual multiplication using for loops.

I've tried a couple things but honestly I just do not know where to go. Here's what I have so far

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int userInputX;
    int userInputY;

    do {
        do {
            cin >> userInputX;

        } while (((1 > userInputX) || (userInputX > 11)));

        do {
            cin >> userInputY;

        } while (((1 > userInputY) || (userInputY > 11)));

        for (int i = 1; i <= userInputY; i++) {
            cout << setw(5) << right << setfill('.') << i;
        }
        cout << '\n';
        for (int k = 1; k <= userInputY; k++) {
            cout << setw(5) << right << setfill('.') << k;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        for (int i = 1; i <= userInputX; i++) {
            cout << setw(5) << right << setfill('.') << i;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    } while (false);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's with that `do {...} while (false);`?

Comment: *"I just do not know where to go"* Try using nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task has been made more complex by the need to print a header row and column.

I'd recommend starting by leaving those out, and just print the multiplications themselves, e.g.

```
...1...2...3...4
...2...4...6...8
...3...6...9..12
```

## Printing just the table

We will need a nested loop for this - an *inner loop* within an *outer loop*.

- The inner loop will output a row (i.e. each number in a row, one number for each column)
- The outer loop will perform the inner loop once for each row.

```
    // outer loop: for each row
    for (int i = 1; i <= userInputY; i++) {
        // inner loop: for each column in the row
        for (int j = 1; j <= userInputX; j++) {
            // [code to print i*j]
        }
        // [code to print a newline after each row]
    }
```

Ultimately the code in the inner loop will be run `(rows * columns)` times, which is what we'd expect.

There are just a couple of blanks to fill in.

We already have the code needed to print a number, padded by dots.  We just have to adapt this to output the product of `i` and `j`, instead of just the loop counter variable on its own.

Once we've done this, we'll have code that can print out the above table.

Now, we have to work out how to add the header row and column.  This is actually two separate tasks:

## Printing the header row

1. To add the header row, we have to add code to just print the numbers `1..userInputX`.
   We've got this code nailed, we just have to add it before our outer loop.

(There's the additional task of adding code to do the blank in the top-left corner.
We'll handle that later with the header column, but for now, what we have will align with the multiplication table.)

```
// row header loop: for each column
for (int j = 1; j <= userInputX; j++) {
    // [code to print each 'j']
}

// outer loop: for each row
...
```

(Oh, and I nearly forgot: after printing the header row, we also have to print a newline after the row header loop, before the outer loop runs.)

## Printing the header column

To add the header row, we have to have to print an additional number once per row, before the first column.
That means we have to put the code for this inside the outer loop, just before the start of the inner loop.

```
    ...
    // outer loop: for each row
    for (int i = 1; i <= userInputY; i++) {
        // [code to print 'i']

        // inner loop: for each column in the row
        ...
```

When we do that, the header row will be misaligned because it needs a `.` in the first column.  We need to add code to do this before printing the header row:

```
// print '.' in top-left corner
// [code to print '.']

// row header loop: for each column
...
```

This is as simple as taking our code for printing a number, and just replacing the number with a `'.'` character.

## Final code structure

What we are left with is this:

```
// print '.' in top-left corner
// [code to print '.']

// row header loop: for each column
for (int j = 1; j <= userInputX; j++) {
    // [code to print each 'j']
}
// [code to print a newline after header row]


// outer loop: for each row
for (int i = 1; i <= userInputY; i++) {
    // inner loop: for each column in the row
    for (int j = 1; j <= userInputX; j++) {
        // [code to print each i*j]
    }
    // [code to print a newline after each row]
}
```

This is the final structure of the code.  All that remains is to fill in the blanks, and place it inside the `main()` function you've provided above, taking out the bits we don't need anymore.